# How do I replicate the Record Button in iOS

Tags: ios, button

I want to replicate the record button with the glowing red middle from the iOS camera app.  Is it available via some framework? Has someone already implemented it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a button you and add UIImageView as a subview and animate when you want it to glow.

To do animation using UIImageView please follow this article. It has source code and sample project implementation.

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

Comment: I was hoping I wouldnt have to go down this route. Are there any resources/tips for generating the animation sequence? Sure there are no existing implementations?